# Testing multiple providers independently in Jersey Testing Framework

Tags: java, junit, jersey-2.0

I'm having an intermittent problem with a couple of my tests. I've done a good bit of hair pulling, in combination with Googling, and have failed to devise a solution.

Given the following simplified test source:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class JsonValueObjectReaderWriterITTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            { Jackson1JsonValueObjectReaderWriter.class },
            { Jackson2JsonValueObjectReaderWriter.class },
            { GsonJsonValueObjectReaderWriter.class }
        });
    }

    public JsonValueObjectReaderWriterITTest(final Class<?> cls) {
        super(new ResourceConfig(cls, JacksonJsonProvider.class, UserResource.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void ensureInvalidEntityConversionReturnsError() throws Exception {
        UserV1 user = new UserV1();
        user.name = "John Smith";

        Response response = target()
                .request("application/json")
                .post(Entity.entity(user, MediaType.valueOf(UserV1.TYPE_STR+".v1+json")));
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(400));
        assertThat(response.readEntity(String.class), anyOf(
                is(equalTo("{\"message\":\"username may not be null\"}")),
                is(equalTo("{\"message\":\"email may not be null\"}"))
        ));
    }

    @Path("/")
    public static class UserResource {
        @POST
        public Response post(@Valid final UserV1 user) {
            assertThat(user.name, is(equalTo("John Smith")));
            assertThat(user.username, is(equalTo("john.smith")));
            assertThat(user.email, is(equalTo("john.smith@example.com")));

            return Response.created(URI.create("/abc123")).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why my provider-under-test, as given in the static `data()` method, fails to register intermittently. In reality, I have those three providers indicated. During any given test run, zero or more will fail to operate. But if tested independently, they all work just fine. If any additional clarification is required, please let me know and I'll provide what is required. I'd rather not muddy the question if possible.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

It seems that the `JacksonJsonProvider` occasionally takes priority over my provider implementation, and passes an empty object into the controller. Adding `@Priority(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` to each provider has reliably fixed the problem, but it feels dirty to do so, especially as this is a library. Is there any way to override the priority for the purpose of testing, but leave it otherwise unspecified?